# MySQLi query looping over array returns throws Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, mysqli

I am performing some queries. Problem is that looping over array throws

> Undefined offset: 1

This is code that I used:

```
$id=1;
$books="";
$prep_stmt= "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
if (!$stmt) {
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
    exit();
}
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
while ($field1 = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    $parameters[] = & $row[$field1->name];
}
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $x[$key] = $val;
    }
    $results[] = $x;
}
if ($stmt->num_rows>0){
    for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($results[0]) - 1; $i++) {
        $id=$results[$i]['id'];
        $name=$results[$i]['name'];
        $books=$books."<option value='".$id."'>".$naziv."</option>";
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)?

Comment: *sidenote:* fyi, `die()` is functioning identical to `exit()`, except `exit()` can provide exit status code when integer is supplied as parameter. In short (already too long), no need to use `die()` along with `exit()`; pick one.

Comment: and the error is due to `$results[1]` may not be defined.

Comment: @Raptor it may not but I don't know why it's not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of rows in `$results` however when looping you loop from 0 to the number of **columns**:

```
$i <= sizeof($results[0])
```

If the number of columns is greater than the number of results you will get an undefined offset. Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($results) - 1; $i++) {
    $id=$results[$i]['id'];
    $name=$results[$i]['name'];
    $books=$books."<option value='".$id."'>".$naziv."</option>";
}
```

or, more succinctly:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $id=$result['id'];
    $name=$result['name'];
    $books=$books."<option value='".$id."'>".$naziv."</option>";
}
```